# Increase the power of tesseract

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project to identify images, however, I'm not getting 100% in my analyzes with tesseract ... is there anything I can do to increase the success rate?

[image]

```
pictureBox2.Image.Save("image.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

var engine = new TesseractEngine(@ "./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default);

engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");

//var imgarray = ImageToByteArray(pictureBox2.Image);

var img = Pix.LoadFromFile("image.bmp");

var page = engine.Process(img);

var result = page.GetText();

label1.Text = "Confidence: " + page.GetMeanConfidence();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) || result == "\n\n")
 textBox3.Text = "Error, cant solve!";
else
 textBox3.Text = result;
```